# mysql_query errors out on a semicolon

Tags: php, mysql

I got this code:

```
set @row_num = 0;
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number,id,name,salary 
FROM employee
ORDER BY salary;
```

This works perfectly with MySQL. The problem comes when I try to execute through PHP using `mysql_query()` function. It gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '; SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as,id,name ' at line 1

I know, the problem comes from `SET @ROW_NUM`, but I need to know why it works in MYSQL, and not on PHP. I can't use any other code, this code is right, and it works, but not in PHP. Why it doesn't work on PHP?

Comment: You are using multiple sql queries. So look into `multi_query()`. Or use the statement of @MahmoudGamal.

Answer (score 7):

Because they are treated as two queries, so you can't run it this way as one query, but you can do this instead:

```
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number,id,name,salary 
FROM employee, (SELECT @rum_num :=0 ) AS t
ORDER BY salary;
```

And please stop using `mysql_query`, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: you mean use PDO **and** prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query **(multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Your query string contains two queries, and so you cannot call it using `mysql_query()`.

In addition, you should note that the PHP `mysql_xxx()` functions are oboslete and deprecated -- again, see the manual page for more on this.

Your best solution is therefore to switch to a more modern database API that supports the features you need. You have two options in PHP: [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). I recommend PDO as it is more flexible, but mysqli is easier to work with if you're already used to using the old mysql functions.